# SharePoint 2010 Performance Point & PowerPivot Software Requirements

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powerpivot, performancepoint

We're currently looking into SharePoint 2010 and we're decided what we need as a business.

We're at a point where we are looking to upgrade our MS SQL Server from 2008 to SQL 2012 Enterprise Edition but mainly on the back of SharePoint features.

Can somebody tell me if SharePoint Enterprise Edition can run Performance Point & PowerPivot off MS SQL Server 2008 or would it require SQL 2012 Enterprise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found you need:

SharePoint Enterprise in order to use PowerPivot and PerformancePoint (dashboard services) with SQL Server 2008 R2 for PowerPivot and PerformancePoint to run.

In this particular case there was no need for us to upgrade.